# Compose Material 3 SearchBar intercepts the click on the trailing button. How to forbid it?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have code like this:

```
SearchBar(
    query = query,
    onQueryChange {},
    onSearch = {},
    active = active,
    onActiveChange = {},
    trailingIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = {}) {
            Icon(
                painterResource(R.drawable.ic_filter_24),
                contentDescription = "Filter",
            )
        }
    },
) {}
```

Pressing the filter button opens the corresponding menu. But if I click on it, it will also expand the `SearchBar` (`onActiveChange` will be called), which is undesirable. Inside the `SearchBar`, there is the following code, which intercepts click events:

```
BasicTextField(
    value = query,
    onValueChange = onQueryChange,
    modifier = modifier
        .height(InputFieldHeight)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            awaitEachGesture {
                // Must be PointerEventPass.Initial to observe events before the text field
                // consumes them in the Main pass
                awaitFirstDown(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)
                val upEvent = waitForUpOrCancellation(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)
                if (upEvent != null) {
                    onActiveChange(true)
                }
            }
        },
        decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
        TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            trailingIcon = trailingIcon?.let { trailing -> {
                Box(Modifier.offset(x = -SearchBarIconOffsetX)) { trailing() }
            } },
        )
    }
)
```

It intercepts any click events that occur on its surface, including its descendants (`trailingIcon`). How to get around this and handle the click only in the `trailingIcon`, prevent the event from being passed below to the `SearchBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the upcoming version of Material 3. check this Fix
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2425374